# Mongoose not calling callbacks of save() and find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not getting into the callbacks for either the save() or find() methods. It's also not getting into the callback for mongoose.connect. Any idea why?

Here's my code:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blah", {
    useMongoClient: true,
}, function (err) {
    console.log('connect to database'); // Not called
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var User = new Schema({
    author    : String
  , type      : String
});

var MyUserModel = mongoose.model('User', User); //create and access the model User

var u = new MyUserModel();
u.author = 'authorname';
u.save(function(err){
    console.log("saved") // not called
    if (err) console.log(err);
});

MyUserModel.find({}, function (err,docs) {
    console.log("found"); // not called
    console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: Are you successfully connecting to the database?

Comment: This line? mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blah", ... ?

Comment: @MikeMiller add the part where you connect to a database and use a collection.

Comment: Show the full code of the `.connect()` in your question. Odds are on that your connect is likely still awaiting promise resolution. Mongoose changed how this is handled in recent months. You basically should be doing `.connect(...).then(...)` or better `await mongoose.connect(...)`.

Comment: See the added code above. I'll try to change it to what you said, though I'm not too familiar with that syntax

Comment: As noted, you added a callback but none of your subsequent code awaits it's completeion. In essence, the rest of your listing ( or at least the actual `.find()` statement ) belongs **inside** the callback, Not "outside" as it presently is. This is how async code works. Make your life easier though and upgrade to a nodejs v8.x.x release ( if you have not already ) and then learn about `async/await` and promises in general. You will find the code much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: Shouldn't it be printing out my first log statement "connect to database," at least? How am I supposed to put the rest of the code in there if the console.log is not even getting called?

Comment: @MikeMiller Firstly see the `@` thingy there? That's how you notify someone of your comment without requiring them to watch your post continually waiting for you to say something. Please use the feature. As to your query, **NO** this is not how async code works. In the context of your listing the whole code is executed "before" any async I/O is being processed. Hence why you put actions in callbacks/promises that need to await something else to happen. Your code likely spits out "connected", but not necessarily "before" that call to `.find()` is being executed.

Comment: So what you really need to do is understand the principles of async code first. Earlier releases of mongoose simply "queued" methods like `.find()` awaiting the "connect" to actually happen. The method they were performing this "black magic" with has been deprecated in the underlying mongo driver, and hence you need to do things "properly" from now on. So methods can only use a connection "after" that connection is established and within the callback or promise resolution. Not outside it.

Comment: @NeilLunn First, thanks for help. Sorry I wasn't using @. I did a little research and wrapped my entire sequence into an async function. Inside I call "await mongoose.connect(...)". The code is not executing past that point, though. Maybe I still don't understand async/await.

Comment: Don't use `useMongoClient: true`

Comment: @robertklep Without useMongoClient: true, I get the following error: (node:14240) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `use
ongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mo
go-client

Comment: @MikeMiller that's a _warning_, not an _error_. But the queries work now, right? If you search here on StackOverflow on _"useMongoClient"_ you'll find loads of questions with the exact same issue; it's related to this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399 (also look [at this comment](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399#issuecomment-322041860) for a better solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "await" the connection before doing anything. It is an "async" function, and like all async functions you need to await their resolution before continuing other code that depends on the result. In this case the "connection" is going to be needed by later actions with the database.

Best done in modern environments with `async/await`:

```
// setup part
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var User = new Schema({
    author    : String
  , type      : String
});

var MyUserModel = mongoose.model('User', User); //create and access the model User

// async parts - wrapped in a self executing closure with the async keyword
(async function() {   

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blah", {
      useMongoClient: true,
    });
    console.log('database connected');

    // Add a user and wait for it to save
    var u = new MyUserModel();
    u.author = 'authorname';
    await u.save();
    console.log("saved");

    // find the documents and await that too
    let docs = await MyUserModel.find();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(docs,undefined,2));

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

Or by chaining promises in older nodejs versions:

```
// setup part
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var User = new Schema({
    author    : String
  , type      : String
});

var MyUserModel = mongoose.model('User', User); //create and access the model User

// Async part
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blah", { useMongoClient: true })
   .then( () => {
     var u = new MyUserModel();
     u.author = 'authorname';
     return u.save();
   })
   .then( () => MyUserModel.find() )
   .then( docs => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(docs,undefined,2));
     mongoose.disconnect();
   })
   .catch( e => console.error(e) );
```

Bottom line is that you need to wait for completion of all async calls and `.connect()` is now an async call in modern mongoose releases. It really should have always been handled like this, but now you "must" handle like this.

Comment: I copied both of your code samples, and in both cases it still hangs during the connect call, and never prints out "database connected" (or gets into the "then" part). Any ideas why? Something must be wrong with my configuration if this works for you but not for me. Node: v8.4.0, mongod db version v3.4.7, mongoose: 4.11.10, express: 4.15.4.

Comment: @MikeMiller Create a fresh directory folder and install only mongoose and the listing here. You might have botched an install. But that is what self contained listings are for. So you should be running this code like that rather than dropping it into your existing project directory.

Comment: Sure enough, that worked. I wonder what I messed up in the install. Well, now I have something to work off of. Thanks a ton!